# SEM single indicator model in lavaan: regressions without intercepts?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am estimating a path model using `R` package `lavaan`. I only have 1 indicator per construct so that I am not using latent constructs nor measurement models. I just have "observed" variables and model relationships among them.

I got a model with decent fit.

Now, I did not specify anything related to intercepts in my syntax. So, my model looked something like:

```
mymodel <- ' 
Y ~ X
Z ~ X + Y
etc.
'
```

So, if I have variables `X` and `Y` - both of which ranged from 1 to 5 and the unstandardized coefficient from `X` to `Y` is 1, then what would be the regression equation for predicting `Y` based on `X`?
`Y = 1*X`? In other words, it'd be a regression without intercept?

Comment: You should really give us more detail using reproducible data, your full model structure, and output to better understand what it is you're doing. I find it highly suspect that you have an estimated coefficient of 1 unless there's something problematic with either your data or model specification.  These aren't really "regressions" and in a typical structural equation modelling context you aren't "fitting" the model in the same way (hence no constants), instead fitting it to the correlation/covariance structure. But simply, you can interpret the unstandardized coefficients in that way...

Comment: I can't put the whole data file and the whole code here. My question is rather simple: If my lavaan's final model output tells me that Z regressed on X + Y has the following 2 coefficients: 1.5 and 2, then can I expect to be able to predict Z like this: Z = 1.5*X + 2 * Y? Or should there be also an intercept? If yes - where do I find it in the output of output <- sem(mymodel, data = mydata)

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is that if your model is only structural with no latent factors and prediction is what you're after, why not just use a multiple linear regression? Or partial linear regression depending on the structure?  (This is where having your model would be necessary for more explicit guidance.) In any case, this is more of a statistical not a programming question and I suggest you move it to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).